# Mysql triggers : OLD and NEW as a string/xml/parameter?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I would like to store all changes to my tables (in MySQL). I created a table 'audit' to track all changes of all tables in one table  (so I don't have to create audit-tables for each table).

I then created triggers for each table and a stored procedure that inserts a record into the audit-table. The parameters for the stored procedure are the tablename and the primary id. Now I'm able to track the insert/update/delete dates for each record in my database.

But I also would like to trace all changes to the DATA with this procedure. For this I'd have to find a way to use the OLD and NEW records from the triggers in the stored procedure.

Anybody know how to do this? 
Maybe some kind of serializing the records OLD and NEW into a string??

Comment: Can't you just pass the acording values to the procedure like regular arguments?

Comment: I could, but then I'd have to write different stored procedures for all my tables, and some tables have more than 50 columns.  Since I use only 1 table for the audit logging, I thought it would be nice if I could pass OLD and NEW as a parameter.... but it isn't possible, as far as I can see...

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I could derive was checking the OLD & NEW values of every field in my table.

```
BEGIN

-- record changes to table log_new

IF OLD.fieldA != NEW.fieldA
OR OLD.fieldB != NEW.fieldB
THEN

INSERT INTO log_new (
```